# I have dynamically added radiogroups to an Activity. I can't get which Radiogroup is selected, but I can see the Radiobutton

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I would like to dynamically add radiogroups into my layout, I could do that. Also I was able to show with a Toast which radiobutton was selected.

The only thing that I could not work out is to show the radiogroup.

The code:

```
             final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[3];
                final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext()); //create the RadioGroup
                rg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
                for(int y=0; y<3; y++){
                    rb[y]  = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
                    rg.addView(rb[y]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
                    if(y==0){
                        rb[0].setText("Chico");
                    }else{
                        if(y==1){
                            rb[1].setText("Mediano");
                        }else{
                            rb[2].setText("Grande");
                        }
                    }
                }



                rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {


                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId) {


                        int pos = rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                        switch (pos)
                        {
                            case 0 :
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked Radio 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                            case 1 :
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked Radio 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                            case 2 :
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked Radio 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                            default :
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Nothing Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Basically, I have made the radiobutton detection work. However, I do not know which line (radiogroup) is selected. There has to be a way.
I tried with `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` but it didn't work.

I hope someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the gravity of your layout params

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
rg.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You may change the kind of layoutparams depending on the ViewGroup you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
int radioButtonID = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = rg.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int index = rg.indexOfChild(radioButton);
```

Comment: That's what I have done till now. What you are saying now, is what I have in the code from above